# Python Try / Except in Selenium aplication performing slowly than should be

Tags: python, performance, selenium, try-except

I have a Selenium script, wherer I'm colecting pacients profiles data from an medical aplication.
Inside the profiles some of them are not completed, so the script trys to find the data and it does not exist. The idea is skip it and just move on but it's getting slowly than it should.
When all the data are filled its work fast, but most of them aren't filled.

Can I improve something on my code to this "skip" be faster?

Thanks in advance.

Below my code:

```
def PACIENTE_SCROLL_CLICA_INFO_FECHA(linha):
    global driver

    if (linha % 30) == 0: #every multiple of 30 it will scroll down 30 pacients
        last_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//md-list-item["+str(linha)+"]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", last_element)

    link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='md-dialog-container']//md-list-item["+ str(linha) +"]//div[1]//a[1]").get_attribute('href') #Looks for the pacient link profile
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');") #creates a new chrome tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #switch to new chome tab
    driver.get(link) #Look at the pacient profile

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.numeroPaciente"'''
        N_do_Paciente = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]/span[2]"))).text
        print(N_do_Paciente)
    except TimeoutException:
        N_do_Paciente = "-"
        print("Loading took too much time!")

    try:
        Nome_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='layout-wrap layout-row']//div[1]//md-card[1]//md-toolbar[1]//div[1]//div[1]").text
        print(Nome_Paciente)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Nome_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem nome cadastrado cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento"'''
        Idade_Paciente = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]/span[2]").text
        print(Idade_Paciente)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Idade_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem idade cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.sexo"'''
        Sexo_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]/span[2]").text
        print(Sexo_Paciente)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Sexo_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem sexo cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.titularPlano"'''
        Plano_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]/span[2]").text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Plano_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem plano cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.bairro"'''
        Bairro_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]/span[2]").text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Bairro_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem o bairro cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.celular"'''
        Cel_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]/span[2]").text
        print(Cel_Paciente)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Cel_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem o celular cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    try:
        ngxpath = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.email"'''
        Email_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@ng-if="+ ngxpath +"]//span[2]").text
        print(Email_Paciente)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Email_Paciente = "-"
        print("Paciente %s não tem o email cadastrado." %(Nome_Paciente))

    driver.close() #close the pacient profile chrome tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) #switch to the main tab
    print("Paciente: %d foi cadastrado." %(linha))

    return N_do_Paciente, Nome_Paciente, Idade_Paciente, Sexo_Paciente, Plano_Paciente, Bairro_Paciente, Cel_Paciente, Email_Paciente
```

This is the Html code from a full profile filled.

```
<div layout="column" flex="50" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="100" class="layout-column flex-xs-100 flex-sm-100 flex-50">
        <md-card class="_md">
            <md-toolbar md-theme="grey" class="_md md-grey-theme _md-toolbar-transitions">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools grey">
                    <div flex="" class="flex">Bernardo dos Santos Junior</div>
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-card-content class="md-body-1 layout-sm-column" layout-sm="column">
                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.celular" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Celular</span>
                    <span>(21) 99979-3331</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.numeroPaciente" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Número paciente</span>
                    <span>2300</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.cpf" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">CPF do paciente</span>
                    <span>337.744.477-85</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.rg" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">RG</span>
                    <span>211588355</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Idade do paciente</span>
                    <span>29 anos
                    </span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Data de nascimento</span>
                    <span>10 de abr de 1991</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.sexo" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Sexo</span>
                    <span>Masculino</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.plano" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Plano</span>
                    <span>Particular</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.titularPlano" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Titular do plano</span>
                    <span>SulAmerica</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.numeroCarteirinha" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Número carteirinha</span>
                    <span>234075700</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->

                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.email" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Email</span>
                    <span>bernardosantos@gmail.com</span>
                </div><!---->

                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.bairro" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Bairro</span>
                    <span>Bangu</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
        <!---->
    </div>
```

Comment: don't use a wait.  This is not necessary (unless some lazy load technique is used) after a .get is used.  Selenium will already wait for a page ready state.

Comment: I'm only using WebDriverWait on the first data collect, after the first it is without waits.

Comment: well it's adding 10 seconds of wait when the element does not exist... it should then throw timeout... I'd suggest catching/logging all exceptions to help troubleshoot.  The switch to window handle may also be incorrect... the order of handles in the array is not guaranteed.  Check full handles array against driver's current handle to be sure.

Comment: also, check the structure of the DOM when the info does not exist.  Do all those spans exist?  You may want to change that XPATH to get the parent elements innerHTML and parse the name from there.  (get attribute innerHTML...)

Comment: @pcalkins I was trying to diggest all the information you said. I'm very new on it and most of the things you said were new to me. So if I wrong in something consider me as learner trying new things, i'm very open to learn. 

First point, the "10 seconds" just removed it. I think it helped a little bit.

Second point, catching/logging (something new to me) I was researching about it and trying to implement it in the code even not understading how it gona help because I alredy know wherer the problem is (at least i think i do). 

Third point, "The switch to window handle" I didn't got it.

Comment: @pcalkins The fourth point, just edited the post with the html code. Answering your question, yes all <span> exists as you can see in the code.

Comment: ah, ok, I thought you said the info did not exist in some cases which was slowing it down.  Looks like it always exists.  Catching the exceptions will help you troubleshoot the cause of the slowdown.  I don't know python, so can't help much with specific code, so hopefully someone else will jump in here with example code.

Comment: @pcalkins the info doesn't exist every time, it depends if it was registered or not. For now we have alot information missing, so it's delaying the try / except.

Comment: post the markup for the use-case where the delay happens.